# Trying to use angular js with codeigniter

Tags: html, angularjs, codeigniter

I am having an issue with using angular js with codeigniter. I am getting no error but the data is not showing up. I am trying to learn how to create a RESTful app with angularjs and Codeigniter if anyone has any example feel free to send me a link also.

CI controller

```
<?php
class MasterController extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }


  function index() {
    $data['pagetitle'] = 'Page for Angular JS';
    $data['viewname'] = 'index';
    $this->load->view('master',$data);
  }

  function json_get_user() {
        $arr = array(
    array( "name" => "smith", "age" => "20", "city" => "adelade", "country" => "australia"),
         array("name" => "john", "age" => "20", "city" => "parth", "country" => "australia" ),
    array("name" => "david", "age" => "20", "city" => "london", "country" => "england")
    );
         echo json_encode($arr);
 }

}
?>
```

CI view

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div class="span6" ng-controller="app_home">
   <p>My name is <em>{{name}}</em></p>
   <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>City</th><th>State</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
      <td>{{user.name}}</td><td>{{user.age}}</td><td>{{user.city}}</td><td>{{user.country}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<script src="<?=base_url()?>app/homeapp.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

homeapp.js

```
var App = angular.module('myApp', []);
function app_home($scope, $http) {
  $scope.name = 'John doe';

  // Initialising the variable.
  $scope.users = [];

  // Getting the list of users through ajax call.
  $http({
    url: base_url + '/masterController/json_get_user',
    method: "POST",
  }).success(function (data) {
    $scope.users = data;
  });
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information. Are you able to fetch data from server? I suspect a JavaScript error.

Comment: I created an array no database no data is being fetched though on the array

Comment: Can you check in your browser console, are you getting JS error? Can you check the request being sent? If at all, response being received?

Comment: no errors on the console no js error just no data showing up

Comment: I see something i forgot to put in ng-controller=“app_home"

Comment: but now I get an error Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'app_home' is not a function, got undefined

Answer (score 0):

You have not added function app_home as a controller in app module.

**//something like below. Note, have not verified the syntax**

```
var App = angular.module('myApp', [$scope]);

App.controller('HomeController', ['$scope','$http', app_home($scope, $http)]);

function app_home($scope, $http) {
  $scope.name = 'John doe';

  // Initialising the variable.
  $scope.users = [];

  // Getting the list of users through ajax call.
  $http({
    url: base_url + '/masterController/json_get_user',
    method: "POST",
  }).success(function (data) {
    $scope.users = data;
  });
}
```

Comment: I am getting $scope is not defined

Comment: pass $scope to module

Comment: still says $scope not define